# datetime.datetime format does not match

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created bellow script to compare date and time in a log file, 
basically the purpose of the script is :

it will go through a log file, it will compare the date of the log line with current time stamp. if any log  line one hour old then current time, it will show the line.

sample log line is :
10.x.x.x - - [16/Jun/2016:09:28:58 -0300] "POST /xxxxx  HTTP/1.1" 200 444
10.x.x.x. - - [16/Jun/2016:09:29:02 -0300] "POST /xxxxx HTTP/1.1" 200 1483

the error i am getting is :

```
Current Time 2016-06-16 09:46:55.887691
LastHour 2016-06-16 08:46:55.887701
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log.py", line 41, in <module>
    log_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(2).rstrip(), "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M").replace(year=datetime.date.today().year)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '0/Apr/2016:00:00' does not match format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M'


import re
import os
import subprocess
import os
import datetime

LOG_FILE="access_log"

#xxxxxxxx - - [26/Apr/2016:14:38:52 -0300] "xxxxxxx HTTP/1.1" 200 357

get_date = re.compile('(.*)([0-9]+/[A-Z-a-z]+/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)(.*)')


current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
lastHourTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)

print ('Current Time %s' % current_time)
print ('LastHour %s' %lastHourTime)


def _read_log():

        with open (LOG_FILE,'r')as f:
                content=f.readlines()
        return content



if __name__ == '__main__':
        log_file=_read_log()

        for line in log_file:
                #GEt the Date only from the log file Feb  7 07:33:19
                match=re.search(get_date,line)
                if match:
                  #Capture only the date field so taht we can compare iet with (current_time and lastHourTime.
                  #log_date1= match.group(2)
                  #print log_date1
                  log_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(2).rstrip(), "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M").replace(year=datetime.date.today().year)

                  #print ('Log Date %s' %log_date)
                  #Check if log_date is greater then lastHourTime and less then current_time
                  if  log_date < current_time and log_date > lastHourTime  :
                        print "Matching"
                        print line
                  else:
                        print "Not Matching"
                        print line
```

'

Comment: I don't think your reading the date correctly. If you look at the string it's trying to convert `'0/Apr/2016:00:00'`, you can see that this doesn't have a day (it's `0`), which is what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your regex.

Instead of capturing `26/Apr/2016:14:38` (in the example in your commented code) it captures `6/Apr/2016:14:38`. As you can see, this raises an exception when the day is `10`, `20` or `30`, and introduces a bug otherwise.

You can simplify your regex to `([0-9]+/[A-Z-a-z]+/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)`, and change `match.group(2)` to `match.group(1)`.

A quick example:

```
import re
import datetime

get_date = re.compile(r'([0-9]+/[A-Z-a-z]+/[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)')

line = 'xxxxxxxx - - [26/Apr/2016:14:38:52 -0300] "xxxxxxx HTTP/1.1" 200 357'

match = re.search(get_date, line)

if match:
    log_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(0).rstrip(), "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M").replace(
                year=datetime.date.today().year)
    print log_date
    >> 2016-04-26 14:38:00
```